# How do i insert these data from mysql into my webpage by php?

Tags: php, mysql

am trying to pull data from database of a number of associated rows into ROW1, ROW2 and ROW3 but using

```
<?php echo $row['']; ?>
```

but it's not working, please any idea

here is my code,

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2,1;";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

}
?>

<li>
<a href="single.html"><img src="images/<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>" alt=""/> 
</a>
<div class="slide-title"><h4><?php echo $row['song_name']; ?></div>
<div class="slide-title"><h4><?php echo $row['artist']; ?></div>
<div button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">BUY</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Well it looks like you are closing your `while` loop before you echo your results. Just move the closing bracket `}` after the closing `</li>`

Comment: should it be like this ? <?php
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2,1;";
 $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

 



        <li>
         
         <div class="slide-title"><h4><?php echo $row['song_name']; ?></div>
         <div class="slide-title"><h4><?php echo $row['artist']; ?></div>
         <div button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">BUY</div>
        
        </li> } ?>

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like you are closing your `while` loop before you echo your results. Just move the closing bracket `}` after the closing `</li>`

Your code should look like this:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2,1;";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<li>
<a href="single.html"><img src="images/<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>" alt=""/> 
</a>
<div class="slide-title"><h4><?php echo $row['song_name']; ?></div>
<div class="slide-title"><h4><?php echo $row['artist']; ?></div>
<div button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">BUY</div>
</li>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you, this one worked thought the photo row is not pulling the picture

Comment: Does the photo field in your database contains the whole filename and extension? Otherwise you might need to add. jpg after you echo the photo

Comment: I've seen why, now it's working very fine, thanks Dimitris Filippou

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2,1;";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        foreach ($row as $data) {
?>
<li>
<a href="single.html"><img src="images/<?php echo $row['photo']; ?>" alt=""/> 
</a>
<div class="slide-title"><h4><?php echo $data['song_name']; ?></div>
<div class="slide-title"><h4><?php echo $data['artist']; ?></div>
<div button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">BUY</div>
</li>
<?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @silvabizhub I do not understand the reason

Comment: Takabrycheri thank you, it opens but there is an error, it says illegal string offset